# Toggle включить/выключить отображение password при нажатии на checkbox

Tags: jquery, toggle, click

Не работает функция, почему?

```js
$('.passwordview input[type=checkbox]').click(
    function(){
    $('.password').attr('type', 'text' )
},
    function(){
        $('.password').attr('type', 'password' );
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-order">
    <input type="text" value="Введите имя">
    <input type="password" class="password" value="Пароль">
    <div class="passwordview"><input type="checkbox"><span>Показать/скрыть пароль</span></div>

</div>
```

При клике на чекбокс должен отображаться пароль, при повторном клике, пароль должен скрываться.

Comment: Возможно то что вы ищите http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 3):

Ваша функция не работает потому, что вы передаёте обработчику click() две функции в качестве аргументов в то время, как он, согласно документации, принимает всего один.

Попробуйте сделать так: https://jsfiddle.net/3er345a5/

js:

```
$('.passwordview input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.is(':checked')) {
    $('.password').attr('type', 'text');
    } else {
    $('.password').attr('type', 'password');
    }
});
```

html

```
<div class="form-order">
    <input type="text" value="Введите имя">
    <input type="password" class="password" value="Пароль">
    <div class="passwordview"><input type="checkbox"><span>Показать/скрыть пароль</span></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. IF'ами уже сделал и сам. Но мне кажется как-то можно было сделать похожим "на мой неверный способ".

Comment: обновила ответ. Ваша функция не работает потому, что вы передаёте обработчику два аргумента, с click() так нельзя